# How to compare if 2 singly linked lists contain the same data (regardless of order)?

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list, traversal

If I have 2 linked lists I would like to compare set up like:

```
ll_1 = ["a"] -> ["b"] -> ["c"] -> NULL  
ll_2 = ["b"] -> ["c"] -> ["a"] -> NULL
```

Both lists would be considered equal since they both contain the same data even though it is in different order.

I know I can loop through 1 linked list by doing:

```
typedef struct Node{
       char key[100]; 
       char data[100];
       struct Node *next; 
}node;
```

```
while (ll_1 != NULL){
       ll_1 = ll_1 -> next; 
}
```

But I do not know how to loop through `ll_2` for each iteration of looping through `ll_1` and comparing their contained data.

Comment: Good! Now copy that while loop and change the name `ll_1` to `ll_2`, and plop that inside your current loop before the line `ll_1 = ll_1 -> next;`

Comment: Easiest way would be to have a nested `while` after the first loop.

Comment: [read up on nested loops](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/nested-loops-in-c-with-examples/)

Comment: To do this efficiently, you are probably going to have to convert them to a different form. If you don't care about the order after, you could do it in-place with [seperate chaining with linked lists hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Separate_chaining_with_linked_lists). It depends on what you want to do if there are duplicates.

Comment: You might consider extracting the values of all the nodes in one list and storing them in a simple array, then sorting that array by value. Then do the same for the 2nd list. Finally, compare the resulting (sorted) arrays.

Comment: Please read [the Open letter to students with questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems). Always post your assignment, verbatim, so we can better assist you in your learning.

Comment: @jarmod, it would be more efficient to build a hash set from one list (and count the nodes), then iterate over the other, looking for any value that isn't in the hash set, if none are found and the final node counts for each of the list is the same, they are equal.

Comment: @jwdonahue most likely, OP would not be allowed to use any external data structures in this assignment.

Comment: @jwdonahue I didn't propose a hashset option under the assumption that values may be repeated in the linked list, but yes if you're careful e.g. [1,2,3] is not equivalent to [1,1,2] but if you do the test wrong (literally as you suggested above) they will be.

Comment: @jarmod, yes, hence the requirement to count the nodes during the hash iterations.

Comment: @SergeyA, that may be true, but we don't know because the OP has presented us with a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) rather than posting their actual assignment. We don't even have an [mcve] to work with. I simply wanted to enforce the idea that there is much for the OP to learn about, and until we know what the assignment is, we can't really do a good teaching job.

Comment: @jwdonahue I agree.

Comment: If you want the same number and type of duplicate nodes, a very natural equivalence relation, you could do it with hash counts instead of hash sets. If you want early rejection, you could put a commutative operation on all the node's hash functions to get one hash for each side.

Comment: If this is a real life case, then you chose the wrong data structure to begin with. Linked lists are not useful for this task. But as you have not been responding since you asked this question, I guess you are not really interested anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add another while loop inside the first loop. With this, for each item in list_1 you check every item of list_2 for a match.

```
while (ll_1 != NULL){
       node *tmp = ll_2; /* have a tmp node, so you can iterate multiple times */
       while (tmp != NULL)
       {
           if (ll_1->data == tmp->data) /* you have to use strcmp() if you are working with strings */
           {
               /* code */
               break;
           }
           tmp = tmp->next;
       }

       ll_1 = ll_1 -> next; 
}
```

Comment: This is probably not going to be a good solution.

Comment: tbh its terrible @jarmod. But judging on the OP's question, any other solution would be **too much**.

Comment: You have to compute the number of elements in both lists--they must be equal. Otherwise `ll_2` could have an extra element that is not in `ll_1` and that would not be detected.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to:

1. Append the elements of ll_1 in array v1 and the elements of ll_2 in array v2.
2. See if the number of elements in v1 and v2 is equal:

   - if it is not, both linked lists are not equal
   - if it is equal, sort both the arrays and compare them using a for loop. Like

```
int i;
int size = //the size of v1 and v2
for( i = 0; i < size; i++){
   if(v1[i] != v2[i])
   {   printf("not equal");
   }
}
```